# who subscribes to PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

usually when a class exposes an event :

```
SomeClass.OnSomeEvent += Handler ;
```

what i'm trying to understand : (correct me if i'm wrong )

when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged the implementing class exposes PropertyChanged event

(1)who registers to that event ?

(2) is there a way to observe the underlying code of the wpf framework ?

Comment: You can decompile the WPF code using Reflector or DotPeek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1)who registers to that event ?

The [`Binding` objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx). They are helper objects, created implicitly when setting up a WPF databinding.

> (2) is there a way to observe the underlying code of the wpf framework ?

You can always use Reflection. But reading the docs and specs will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

1. `DataBinding` subscribes to that event and when you raise it, it updates UI accordingly.
2. Can not observe it, cause it is all about framework internals but can profile it, if this can help you in terms of *this* question.